# Adding a delayed trigger to lightbox2

Tags: javascript, jquery, lightbox2

I've set up Lightbox2 to make an image pop up on page load by using this code that I found on another post:

```
<script>$(document).ready(function(){$("#popimg").trigger('click')});</script>
```

I want to delay the popup and not start immediately on load. What do I need to add to the script to make this work? I can't seem to figure it out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [setTimeout](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers/setTimeout) or jQuery's [delay](https://api.jquery.com/delay/)

Here is an example with `setTimeout` where 2000 is equal to 2 seconds.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  window.setTimeout(function () {
    $("#popimg").trigger('click');
  }, 2000);
});
```

Comment: That did the trick! Wish I knew javascript better. Thank you so much!